# How to find most similar to an array in gensim

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, gensim

I know the `most_similar` method works when entering a previously added string, but how do you *reverse* search a numpy array of some word?

```py
modelw2v = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz',binary=True)
differenceArr = modelw2v["King"] - modelw2v["Queen"]


# This line does not work
modelw2v.most_similar(differenceArr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `most_similar()` method can take vectors as the origin of a search, but you should explicitly specify them as one member of a list provided to the method's `positive` parameter, so that its logic for handling more simple origins (like a string or list of strings) isn't confused.

Specifically, this should work with your other code:

```
model23v.most_similar(positive=[differenceArr,])
```

More generally, you can supply lists of vectors (or word-keys for looking up vectors) to both the `positive` and `negative` parameters of this method, and the method will combine them (according to the exact logic you can see in the source code). So for example the prominent word2vec example...

```
wv('king') - wv('man') + wv('woman') = ?
```

...can be effected with the `most_similar()` method without doing your own other vector-arithmetic:

```
sims = modelw2v.most_similar(positive=['king', 'woman'], negative=['man'])
```